# Using { and } instead of <?php and ?> tags?

Tags: php, html, tags

I have seen many people in templates put things like

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="{VAR_NAME}" ?>
</form>
```

Would anyone happen to know what this is? I have also seen `{TEMPLATE_PATH}` used in some wordpress situations? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "many people"? Linking to an example would probably answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code you wrote found between the php start and finish markers?  If so, the {$VAR_NAME} is simply a way for PHP to place the contents of a variable inside of an echoed string at the specified location.  See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) for the PHP documentation on the echo command.  This works the same way for the print command as well, and for defining the contents of any given string before use.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like it could be [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: @Darayus: It could just be [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) with a regular expression like `/\{([^}]*?)\}/`. (although I bet it *is* a library)

Answer (score 2):

The templating library might be xtpl, or a custom one.

http://eeperry.wordpress.com/2009/08/08/php-xtemplate-the-basics/